# What are the differences between Vimeo Advance API and their New API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Does anyone know that what are the differences between Vimeo Advance API and their New API?

Answer (score 2):

The new API is a ground up redesign.  It's modeled on using RESTful principles, versus the old more RPC style approach.  Instead of specifying *what* you want to do in the URL, you do so with the HTTP verbs common across many modern APIs.

For instance: "GET /me" is how you describe "get the current authenticated user."  The old API describes this same action as "GET /api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.people.getInfo".

There are also other changes to authentication (oAuth 2 versus 1.0a - much simpler to handle) and semantic changes to the responses so you don't have to track IDs and many of the URLs are generated for you to alter.

It's a lot nicer to work with than the old one in my opinion, and it's enabled much faster development in my experience.

Disclosure:  I work on building the new API.